# assembly aarch64 get current unix timestamp

Tags: linux, assembly, arm64

I expect I can get current nanosecond or microsecond unix timestamp from syscall then stored into a register for example register `x0`.

I read this [arch64 syscall table](https://thog.github.io/syscalls-table-aarch64/latest.html), it seems I can use it for `0x99` in `x8` register but I'm not sure how to use it. It seems the return value of timestamp will be stored in register `x0` as `struct tms __user *tbuf`

I tried this simple asm code

```
_start:
mov x8, 0x99
svc 0
```

In debugger, after `svc` executed, it had value `1725984227` in `x0` or `0x66e06de3` in hexadecimal form.

What does it mean? The current timestamp should be 16xxx...xx but it started with 17xxx..xx

Comment: Also, note that on most modern OSes, getting the current time is *not* implemented as a syscall at all.It's usually what is called a VDSO.

Comment: I'm using Android/Linux as OS

Comment: also, the table you're referring to [links to the relevant documentation of `times`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html), which describes what it is that you get.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: The Linux kernel does handle call number for syscalls that are also available via the VDSO, so you *can* just use `svc` for calls like `times` or `clock_gettime` if you're writing toy programs in asm and care more about simplicity than efficiency.

Comment: @PeterCordes true, I was messing that up. but if you care about simplicity and not efficiency, you wouldn't be using assembler (at least on aarch64, where space probably doesn't matter)

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Some people like to learn asm by playing around with toy programs to see if it works.  That's the use-case, simplicity of the learning-asm process in terms of starting with basics like making a syscall via the standard ABI, not of creating a program in any language that makes those system calls. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes absolutely! I should probably be a bit more careful in my wording, and encouraging :)

Comment: @MarcusMuller so why syscall is not efficient?

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira because you trigger a context switch! You completely have to save the state of the process doing the syscall – registers, memory maps, then you need to load the kernel state (same thing, different privilege), flush out a lot of caches, do what you actually wanted to do in the kernel, figure out which process to execute next (which probably is not the one that made the syscall if the system is busy!), do a few information leak mitigations (thank you, meltdown/spectre), restore memory maps and registers of the process and continue running – all in the name of getting the

Comment: current time, which by the the point it can be read from the process isn't that current anymore :) Since there's technically no reason why reading the processor special function registers necessary to implement this functionality has to happen in kernel context, it's advantageous to just implement this as a "normal" userland function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PeterCordes mention, you can use `times` or `clock_gettime`.

But I prefer `clock_gettime` with kernel convention `0x71` in register `x8` according your refference table.

Here is my code, note that I'm using modular programming assembly so `.include` is needed.

```
.data
//reseve 8 bytes for second and 8 bytes for nanosecond
TIME_OUTPUT: .zero 16

//line feed alloc for print newline
LF: .ascii "\n"

.text
.global _start
.include "exit.s" // import exit
.include "print.s" // import print library

_start:

 // getting current timestamp
 mov x0, 0 // x0=0 means CLOCK_REALTIME
 ldr x1, =TIME_OUTPUT // store output in specified addres
 mov x8, 0x71 // kernel convention
 svc 0 //execute

 // processing output
 ldr x2, [x1] // load second
 ldr x3, [x1, 8] // load nanosecond
 ldr x4, =1000000000 //nanosecond unit for multiplier
 mul x2, x2, x4 // multiply second
 add x0, x2, x3 // add second + nanosecond store in x0

 // print Unsigned Integer 64bit
 bl _print_u64 // the argument is in x0 which unsigned integer in bin>

 // print Line Feed (newline)
 ldr x0, =LF
 mov x1, 1
 bl _print

_exit:
 exit 0 // just exit gracefully with exit code 0
```

Output:

```
1657248826648171250
```

So you must make `print.s` if you didn't make print function yet.

```
/* Function Usage
_print <x0: start address> <x1: length>
 "Print string based on address offset and length."
eg: mov x0, 0x12345; mov x1, 5; bl _print

_print_uint64 <x0: uint64 in binary form>
 "Print string char format from uint64."
eg: mov x0, #12345; bl _print_uint64 // 12345
*/

/* Macro Usage
print_str <string>
 "Print string to the standard output."
eg: print_str "Hello world!\n"

print_uint64 <uint64>
 "Print string char format from uint64 to the stdout."
eg: print_uint64 123456
*/

// Register Dependencies: x0 until x8


.type _print, @function
.global _print
_print: //args: x0 start_address, x1 length
  mov x2, x1; mov x1, x0 //moving arguments x0, x1
  mov x0, 1; mov x8, 0x40; svc 0 //system call
  ret //void

.type _print_u64, @function
_print_u64: //args: x0 uint64 in binary form
 mov x1, 10 //divisor
 mov x5, 0 //total digit
 _dividing:
  udiv x2, x0, x1; msub x3, x2, x1, x0 //x2 quotient, x3 remainder
  add x4, x3, 0x30 //convert remainder to ascii char
  sub x5, x5, 1; strb w4, [sp,x5] //store ascii char
  mov x0, x2; cmp x0, 0; b.ne _dividing //jump if quotient not zero
 mov x0, sp; add x0, x0, x5 //x0 args
 neg x1, x5 //x1 args
 mov x6, lr //backup lr
 bl _print
 mov lr, x6 //restore lr
 ret //void

.macro print_str string
 .pushsection .data
 str\@: .ascii "\string"
 len\@= .-str\@
 .popsection
 ldr x0, =str\@
 mov x1, len\@
 bl _print
.endm

.macro print_u64 unsigned_int64
 .pushsection .data
 uint64\@: .8byte \unsigned_int64
 .popsection
 ldr x0, uint64\@
 bl _print_uint64
.endm
```

And `exit.s`

```
/*
exit <code>
  "Exit the program with code, 0 means success."
eg: exit 0
*/

.macro exit code
 mov x0, #\code
 mov x8, #0x5d
 svc #0
.endm
```

Here is summary explanation:
You just need focus to `getting current timestamp` and processing output (optional).

You will get return value which will be stored in memory address that stored in register `x1`. For example current second is
`1657248826` in `[x1]`.
Current nanosecond is
`648171250` in [x1,8]

Then in `processing output`
You just need make like this

```
ts = 1657248826
ts = ts * 1000000000 // because there are 9 zeros for nano unit
ts = ts + 648171250
/So the final is
ts = 1657248826648171250
```